# How to update composer on laravel 4.2 on live site?

Tags: php, php-5.6, laravel-4.2

I  want to update the composer on the live server for the PDF service provider.
But I am not getting any solution for the same.

I am use the puTTY and Command Prompt But not getting any solution regarding update composer on live site.

I am use the below step on cmd
*** FTP 
1. User name
2. Password
3. Dir
4. composer update***

But it's give invalid command error.
Please help me for the same.

Comment: The easiest way would be to deploy your application as an artifact. Then you don't need to install Composer on the server, but only locally or in your CI environment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in locally I face the another problem. In windows os Aux name not supported. And in the my application one aux name namespace than not exequit the site in local. Basically this application not developed by me. I want just fixed pdf issue.  
If you have any solution regarding support the aux file in windows than its really helpful me.....thanks for answer

Comment: Yes, AUX is a reserved filename on Windows. Alternatively, you can generate a zipped Artifact within VirtualBox (Linux as guest OS) and deploy the ZIP file to the prod server.

Answer (score 0):

have you installed composer on the live server? if not, read [this](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)

try `composer --version`. if there is a version, you have installed it.

the problem may be that you didn't move composer to bin folder and hence the server doesn't recognize it. I mean this part of the manual:
`mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

if you are not the root user of your server, there is a high chance you won't have permission to `composer update`, so the only way you can update your files would be to directly upload the vendor folder to your server.